# How can I make my div element move more than 200px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a project using jQuery where i have a div element that says "click," and when you try to click on it, it moves to a random location within the window. The issue I'm having is that every once in a while the div will move only a little bit, leaving the cursor still inside of the div, allowing the user to click on the link.

I'm fairly new at javascript and I'm not too sure how I should go about doing something like this.

I was thinking I could do something like subtracting the new position from the old one and checking to see if they have a difference of less than 200px, and if they do, recalculating the numbers. If that isn't how you would do it, I'm completely open to other methods.

```js
function setPosition() {
   var randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - 200));
   var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - 200));

   $('#square').animate({
     top: randY + 'px',
     left: randX + 'px'
   }, 200);
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
   setPosition()
   var tries = 0;
   //tries is just to stop it after it reaches 1000.
   //I'm planning to make some kind of page to congradulate you on wasting your time.


   $('#square').mouseenter(function() {
     if (tries < 1000) {
       setPosition();

       tries += 1;
       console.log(tries)
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
#square {
  background: orange;
  height: 115px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
h3,
h3 * {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=square.css>
  <script src=jquery-1.11.3.min.js></script>
  <script src=square.js></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id=square>
    <h3><a href=''>Click</a></h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your suggested solution sounds straightforward enough to me. I'd try that if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you might want to run your randomization logic until it finds a combination that is more than 200 pixels away from it's current location.

Off the top of my head, that'd be something like this:

```
function setPosition() {
   var $square = $('#square');
   var prevY = $square.offset().top;
   var prevX = $square.offset().left;
   var randY, randX;

   do {
       randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - 200));
       randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - 200));
   } while( Math.abs(randY - prevY) < 200 || Math.abs(randX - prevX) < 200 );

   $square.animate({
     top: randY + 'px',
     left: randX + 'px'
   }, 200);
 }
```

Comment: I'd go a step further and see if the point is actually more than 200px away in total: `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(randY - prevY, 2) + Math.pow(randX - prevX, 2)) > 200` - using trigonometry.

Comment: That's probably a good idea. It's probably also a good idea to use the center of the square instead of the top-left corner, i.e. `$square.offset().top + $square.outerWidth() / 2` and `top: randY - $square.outerWidth() / 2 + 'px'`.